# Localized message templates in windows installer ExternalUI callback

Tags: windows, installation

I have a C++ program that installs a .msi file silently, while instructing windows installer to call my callback and I'll show the (progress) UI. I do this using MsiOpenPackage() to open the .msi file, MsiSetExternalUI() to ask windows installer to call my callback and then MsiDoAction() to install.

On my callback, I get several message types, one being INSTALLMESSAGE_ACTIONDATA. In this case the third parameter to my callback (LPCTSTR szMessage) is a message of the following form:

File: btn_exit_up.bmp,  Directory: C:\Program Files\My App\Skin\Dark\Default_frame\,  Size: 2432

The above message is sent during copying new files. There are other such messages, depending on what the installer is doing. I do not know what operation the installer is doing, I only get these messages. I need to parse these messages to extract the information and show it nicely in my UI. I am using regular expressions to do this. My problem is that if my program is run on a non-english system, the messages will be localized when they arrive in my callback (instead of File: there will be Datei: etc).

I found these messages in the table ActionText in the .msi. This table can be localized. So I thought to load the table at the beginning of the installation and build my regular expression from the templates there. Works fine, except that my .msi is NOT localized, the table is only in english, but even so if my program is run an a German OS, the messages still come in localized.

How can I get the localized templates that windows installer will be using for ACTIONDATA messages, even if those templates are NOT coming from my .msi file?